# react navigation the reset action not working

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

index.js have code like this that have StackNavigator

```
const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
  },
});

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: SignIn,
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignUp,
    },
    myApp: { screen: App },
  },
  {
    gestureEnabled: false,
    headerMode: 'none',
  },

);
```

I am doing login and pushing to myApp route,

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(
      NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        key: null,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'myApp' })]
      })
    );
```

all navigation push and pop goback working now I am trying to resection thats not working .

from home I want to go login screen .I am making logout action

```
logoutPressed() {

    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
              index: 0,
              actions: [NavigationActions.navigate ({ routeName:  
              'Login' })],
     });

     this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);

}
```

ERROR: `routeName: 'Login' not found in StackNavigator` whats issue . how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write stack navigator as follows

```
 const App = StackNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: Home,
      },
      Login: {
        screen: SignIn,
      },
  });
```

The **App** StackNavigator has no route for Login you need to have the route name in its navigation